# Create a custom keyboard dictionary

Tags: keyboard, dictionary, auto-correct

Is it possible to use custom dictionary with the default Android keyboard? I guess the words are stored in some file, so I would like to edit it.

The goal is to create Macedonian auto-completion because there is no other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but Smartkeyboard Pro (2-3 Euro) and MultiLingual keyboard both have Macddonian layouts and remember new words. You can teach them while typing, if this is any good for you. 
The market shows a few Macedonian specific keyboards, but I assume you have tried this already.